# Projecting a surface segment of a cone onto a 2D plane?

Tags: geometry

Firstly, I'd like to apologise - I do not know the correct terms for what I am asking.

[image: Diagram showing a section of a cone highlighted]

Assume that the top/bottom of the highlighted portion there is actually aligned with the base.

To help explain:
I need to wrap that section of the cone using a piece of paper. What shape (exactly) do I need to cut out from said paper so that it will wrap flawlessly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, I think this should help. This one's a right circular cone and its opened up paper version. Here we've taken an arbitrary curved surface of the form shown on the cone and visualized.
[image]

Comment: What about r? Would that affect the space seen on the paper cutout?

Comment: It depends. If $a$ and $b$ are given to you, then $r$ is not needed. If the perpendicular heights $h_a$ and $h_b$ are what's given, you will need $r$ to find $a$ and $b$, respectively.

Comment: @genepeer Agreed... and obviously the outer circular perimeter of the paper cutout is $2\pi r$.

Comment: Don't mind me, just forgetting very basic geometry here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the distance from the apex to the base is constant. Assuming the cone is made of paper,  cutting it open along your yellow line will make a circular sector whose radius is the former distance. Your cross-sections will correspond to bands concentric with the sector's circumference.